# Angular 8: Pipe filter doesnot work on reactive form value update?

Tags: html, angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-pipe

Why angular pipe does not filter the reactive form value after updating the form?

here i have this `filterfunction` to transform the value, i had used custom pipe and added the filter to it. But for giving an example i had written that function in ts file.

After updating some new values to the form, the custom pipe(filterfunction) doesnot transform the values, how can we do that?

```js
fg: FormGroup;

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.fg = this.fb.group({
    name1: 1.3,
    name2: 33.34,
    name3: 3.5
  });
}

reload() {
  this.fg.patchValue({
    name1: 10.9999999,
    name2: 20.22222,
    name3: 30
  });
}

filtervalue(value) {
  const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat("en-US", {
    style: "currency",
    currency: "USD",
    minimumFractionDigits: 2
  });
  return formatter.format(value);
}
```

`html`

```html
<form [formGroup]="fg">
  <input formControlName="name1" [value]="filtervalue(fg.get('name1').value)">
  <input formControlName="name2" [value]="filtervalue(fg.get('name2').value)">
  <input formControlName="name3" [value]="filtervalue(fg.get('name3').value)">
</form>
<input type="button" value="reload" (click)="reload()">
{{fg?.value |json}}
```

here is the output for the first time:

$1.30

$33.34

$3.50

but when i patch the new values to form, it does not show the value transformed, it just displays the value patched

10.999999

20.22222

30

I want to tranform the values after updating like currency pipe.

The main issue is that currency pipe does not work when we update the form. So how can i solve the issue?

Comment: Can you please elaborate the issue?

Comment: updated the question pls check.